# find unique pythagorean triples

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to exclude the repeat triangles from a sequence of Pythagorean triples which just prints triangles with hypotenuses of 100, but what I do in the exclusion part fails... I have what follows:

```
....
    int one_hundred = 0,
     if( (a*a) + (b*b) == (h*h) ){

        //exclusion
        if((a == b)){

           continue;

        }else {

       //Just prints the the triangles that have hypotenuses of 100
      if(h == 100){
            cout <<  a << "     " << b << "     " << h << endl;

           }

      .....

     }
```

Now the output for this should be

[image]

What I mean by repeat is that the first and the last rows have the same set of pairs of sides

What I would like to is an output like this:

[image]

But this I do as follows:

//see if they are repeats

```
if((a == 96)){

    continue;

    }
```

And I thought that by comparing a == b I would have achieved the same but I did not:

```
if((a == b)){

    continue;

    }
```

Hopefully this clarifies what I am trying to do...

Thank you again!!

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here.  Please describe exactly what the problem is (i.e. what behaviour you got, and what behaviour you were expecting).  Also `(a == b) || (b == a)` is redundant...

Comment: What do you mean by "repeat triangles"?

Comment: You're not checking for a repeat. You're checking to see if a==b and you're doing it redundantly because (a==b) == (b==a) always.

Comment: Also note that a Pythagorean triple can never contain the same number twice.

Comment: Sorry I explain myself... I am trying to exclude the triangles which have pairs of sides that are like this {a=4, b=3, c=10} and {a=3, b=4 , c =10} I am editing the formulation of the question....

Comment: @user1179105 why would you allow this to happen? Just make sure that `a < b` always (so if you try values for `b`, make sure that you don't try anything that is smaller than `a`). However, raukh has given you the better approach for systematically generating the triangles.

Comment: @Omri I have edited the formulation to make my question clearer... I did not mean repeat numbers ... rather repeat sets of sides ... ex(4,3) (3,4)

Comment: If you make sure that `bside` is never smaller than `aside` you should do just fine... You didn't tell us how you find `a` and `b` - do you simply loop over every possible value between 1 and 100?

Comment: Thank yo Omri I have solved it the way you explained....  a and b with a loop  for (a = 1; a<= SIZE; a++){for(b = 1; b <= SIZE; b++){.. SIZE is a sample size say for example 500... it is really a sample of the triangle Population size that I wanted..

Comment: `int one_hundred = 0,`? Really?

Comment: @user1179105: Not sure it's still relevant, but my suggestion was to change the second loop to `for (b = a+1; b <= SIZE; b++)` in order to make sure that `b>a` always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple approach would be to create a `std::vector<bool> state(h);` Because `h` is the largest of all sides the others could never be larger; right? And we know no other number multiplied by itself could equal another multiplied by itself, otherwise you could say something like **5*5 = 4*4**! So, you can use the vector subscripts as representatives of the numbers. As you pull one number and find it is a solution to your problem simply switch its state to `false`. The whole thing would go something like this -

```
bool loop;
std::vector<bool> *state = new std::vector<bool>(h, true);
for(int i = 2; i != sizeof(bool) * h; ++i)
{
    if((state + i))
    {
        a = i;
        loop = true;

        for(int j = i + 1; loop && j != sizeof(bool) * h; ++j)
        {
            if((state + j))
            {
                b = j;          

                if((a*a) + (b*b) == (h*h))
                {
                    loop = false;
                    (*state)[i] = false;                                                      
                    (*state)[j] = false;
                    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << h << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
28 96 100
60 80 100
```

Which is what I think you meant in your desired results example. Otherwise you need to create a rule that does double print certain ones. In that case you could add a `switch(){}`. Not so hard, granted it's not all that elegant, imoo.

**Note:**
It really isn't necessary to change `state->at(i)` to `false` for `i` is incremented and will never be touched again. But it's there in case you'd need to use the subs later on. Indexes 0 and 1 have been ignored for no side of a triangle can be 0 and if one was viable the other side would have to equal `h` so don't waste precious time. If you do indeed hold on to them remember that 0 and 1 are `true` to begin with and should be set to false.

Answer (score 3):

Filtering out duplicates from a sequence of Pythagorean triples is pretty difficult, because you need to remember all old triples permanently, for a huge number of comparisons.

A better approach is simply not to generate repeats to begin with. To do this, you can use this set of formulae (from [the "Generating a triple" section of the Wikipedia article on Pythagorean triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple)):

> *a* = *k*·(*m*<sup>2</sup> - *n*<sup>2</sup>) 
>   *b* = *k*·(2*mn*) 
>   *c* = *k*·(*m*<sup>2</sup> + *n*<sup>2</sup>)

where *k*, *m*, and *n* are positive integers, with *m* and *n* being coprime (meaning their greatest common denominator is 1) and either *m* or *n* being even.

Answer (score 0):

How about (if (abs (a-b) < EPSILON)) continue...

Also, use the same inequality (define EPSILON somewhere) in the first if structure.

It's been a while since I did C-coding, but equality in double or floating point numbers used to get wrong results. Unless they are all integers, in which case (a==b) is same as (b==a), not sure why you have both.

Comment: _why_ would he ever use floating point numbers for pythagorean triplets?! the whole point of it is the integrality!

Comment: true, I take that back. I was wondering why the OP was trying a==b || b==a

Comment: oh I see. Well even with floating point numbers `a==b || b == a` is equivalent to `a==b` and both expressions have nothing to do with the wanted behaviour, but I see how you ended up thinking about floats